# Problems using large custom stopword lists in tm package (R)

Tags: r, tm

I'm sure that many of you have seen this before:

```
Warnmeldung:

In mclapply(content(x), FUN, ...) :

  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
```

This time, I get the error, when I try to remove a custom stopword list from my corpus.

```
asdf <- tm_map(asdf, removeWords ,mystops)
```

It works with small stopword list (I tried until 100 or something), but my current stopword list has about 42000 words.

I have tried this:

```
asdf <- tm_map(asdf, removeWords ,mystops, lazy=T)
```

this won't give me back an error, however every tm_map command after this will give me the same error above and when I try to compute a DTM from the corpus:

```
Fehler in UseMethod("meta", x) : 

  nicht anwendbare Methode für 'meta' auf Objekt der Klasse "try-error" angewendet

Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:

In mclapply(unname(content(x)), termFreq, control) :

  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code
```

I am thinking about a function, looping the removeWords command for little parts of my list, but I would too like to understand, why the length of the list is a problem..

Here my sessionInfo():

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

locale:
[1] de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8/C/de_DE.UTF-8/de_DE.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] SnowballC_0.5.1    wordcloud_2.5      RColorBrewer_1.1-2 RTextTools_1.4.2   SparseM_1.74       topicmodels_0.2-4  tm_0.6-2          
[8] NLP_0.1-9         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.7         splines_3.3.2       MASS_7.3-45         tau_0.0-18          prodlim_1.5.7       lattice_0.20-34     foreach_1.4.3      
 [8] tools_3.3.2         caTools_1.17.1      nnet_7.3-12         parallel_3.3.2      grid_3.3.2          ipred_0.9-5         glmnet_2.0-5       
[15] e1071_1.6-7         iterators_1.0.8     modeltools_0.2-21   class_7.3-14        survival_2.39-5     randomForest_4.6-12 Matrix_1.2-7.1     
[22] lava_1.4.5          bitops_1.0-6        codetools_0.2-15    maxent_1.3.3.1      rpart_4.1-10        slam_0.1-38         stats4_3.3.2       
[29] tree_1.0-37
```

**EDIT:**

[20 newsgroups dataset](http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/)

I use 20news-bydate.tar.gz and only the train folder.

I won't share all the preprocessing I am doing, as it includes a morphological analysis of the whole thing (not with R).

Here my R code:

```
library(tm)
library(topicmodels)
library(SnowballC)

asdf <- Corpus(DirSource("/path/to/20news-bydate/train",encoding="UTF-8"),readerControl=list(language="en"))
asdf <- tm_map(asdf, content_transformer(tolower))
asdf <- tm_map(asdf, removeWords, stopwords(kind="english"))
asdf <- tm_map(asdf, removePunctuation)
asdf <- tm_map(asdf, removeNumbers)
asdf <- tm_map(asdf, stripWhitespace)  
# until here: preprocessing


# building DocumentTermMatrix with term frequency
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(asdf, control=list(weighting=weightTf))


# building a matrix from the DTM and wordvector (all words as titles, 
# sorted by frequency in corpus) and wordlengths (length of actual 
# wordstrings in the wordvector)
m <- as.matrix(dtm)
wordvector <- sort(colSums(m),decreasing=T)
wordlengths <- nchar(names(wordvector))

names(wordvector[wordlengths>22]) -> mystops1  # all words longer than 22 characters
names(wordvector)[wordvector<3] -> mystops2 # all words with occurence <3
mystops <- c(mystops1,mystops2) # the stopwordlist

# going back to the corpus to remove the chosen words
asdf <- tm_map(asdf, removeWords ,mystops)
```

This is where I get the error.

Comment: The length is probably a problem because afaik `removeWords` concatenate all words into a regular expression (separated by the or pipe `|`). I dunno where the character limit is, but I guess a few thounsand words is clearly too much. In addition, please edit your post and make the example reproducible as asked by the R tag (hover over it). `tm` has an example corpus `data("crude")` and you can easily create artificial stopwords using e.g. `stringi::stri_rand_strings`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected in the comment: `removeWords` from the `tm` package uses perl regular expressions. All words are concatenated using the or `|` pipe. And in your case the resulting string has too many characters:

> Error in gsub(regex, "", txt, perl = TRUE) :    invalid regular
>   expression
>   '(*UCP)\b(zxmkrstudservzdvunituebingende|zxmkrstudservzdvunituebingende|...|unwantingly|
>   In addition: Warning message: In gsub(regex, "", txt, perl = TRUE) :
>   PCRE pattern compilation error    'regular expression is too large'   at
>   ''

One solution: define your own `removeWords` function, which splits a  regular expression that is too large at the character limits, and then applies each split regular expression seperately, so that it does not hit the limit anymore:

```
f <- content_transformer({function(txt, words, n = 30000L) {
  l <- cumsum(nchar(words)+c(0, rep(1, length(words)-1)))
  groups <- cut(l, breaks = seq(1,ceiling(tail(l, 1)/n)*n+1, by = n))
  regexes <- sapply(split(words, groups), function(words) sprintf("(*UCP)\\b(%s)\\b", paste(sort(words, decreasing = TRUE), collapse = "|")))
  for (regex in regexes)  txt <- gsub(regex, "", txt, perl = TRUE)
  return(txt)
}})
asdf <- tm_map(asdf, f, mystops)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your custom stopwords is too big, so you have to break it down:

```
group <- 100
n <- length(myStopwords)
r <- rep(1:ceiling(n/group),each=group)[1:n]
d <- split(myStopwords,r)

for (i in 1:length(d)) {
  asdf <- removeWords(asdf, c(paste(d[[i]])))
 }
```

Comment: Thanks I have used this. Oddly, my same code didn't throw this error before an R update - something must have changed in the regex implementation.